# Access Instance variable in ruby

Tags: ruby, instance-variables

I am trying to run the code below in ruby. I am getting a nil value for @selectcells. Any suggestions?

```
class Neighbor_finder


@@path = "/home/xyz"

def initialize(enodebid,earfcn_dl,distance,spread,mcc,mnc)
@site_details=Hash.new
@radius = distance
@earfcn_dl=earfcn_dl
@spread=spread
@sourceenb=enodebid 
@plmn=mcc+mnc 
@mcc=mcc
@mnc=mnc
puts "here"
end

def enodeb_cell_finder
    enodebid=@sourceenb
    earfcn_dl=@earfcn_dl
    con=Mysql.new 'localhost','root','root','celldb'
    puts "here11"
    @site_details=con.query "SELECT * FROM enodeb WHERE enodeb_id LIKE '%#{enodebid}%'"

    u = @site_details.fetch_hash
    ap u
    con.close

   @con1 = Mysql.new 'localhost','root','root','celldb' 
    @selectnodes1 = @con1.query "SELECT * FROM cell_db_eutran_cells WHERE sitename LIKE  '%#{enodebid}%' AND earfcn_dl LIKE '#{earfcn_dl}'"

    @selectcells=@selectnodes1.num_rows


    end
 end


d=Neighbor_finder.new("936144","2581",20,60,'311','850').enodeb_cell_finder

ap @selectcells
```

---

When I add an ap @selectcells as shown below I do got a valid value. It just appears I can't access value of the instance variable @selectcells from outside.

```
    @selectcells=@selectnodes1.num_rows
    ap @selectcells
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a getter to the class to make it accessible. It is **an instance variable** after all, and you are trying to get it as if it were a global one:

```
def selectsells
  @selectsells
end
# or: attr_reader :selectsells
```

And access it via:

```
d = Neighbor_finder.new("936144","2581",20,60,'311','850')
ap d.enodeb_cell_finder
ap d.selectsells
```

Comment: I added the new method. Now I am getting the error - `<main>': undefined method `selectcells' for 3:Fixnum (NoMethodError) - BTW 3 is the correct VALue of @selectcells                                                          
     def selectcells
        @selectcells
     end

Comment: @ssharma `d` is supposed to be an instance of `Neighbor_finder`. I have updated the answer.